# Reference next element in map function

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to calculate the time period between two appointments.

They are in this format:

```
const events = [
{
   start: eventStart,
   end: eventEnd
},
{
   start: eventStart,
   end: eventEnd
},
// more Events
]
```

Then I tried mapping over this array, referencing the next element to define the end of the "empty" period.

```
const empty = events.map((element, index, array) => {
   const obj = {
      start: element.end,
      end: array[index + 1].start
   }
   return obj
})
```

this works mostly fine, however the last element will throw an error since it can't reference the next element.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
```

How would you solve that problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can use if condition to check the index === array.length-1

Comment: How many elements do you expect the `empty` result to have? If the same number as `events`, then what should the value of `end` become for the last element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last element is a "special case", or "edge case", I would update the code to reflect this. The most straightforward way is to add an `if` that checks for that special case. In your case, the special case is the last element:

```js
const events = [{
    start: "a",
    end: "b"
  },
  {
    start: "c",
    end: "d"
  },
  {
    start: "e",
    end: "f"
  }
];

const empty = events.map((element, index, array) => {
  let obj;

  if ((events.length - 1) === index) {
    // Last element, do something special?
    obj = {
      start: element.end,
      end: undefined,
      lastElement: true
    }
  } else {
    obj = {
      start: element.end,
      end: array[index + 1].start
    }
  }
  return obj
});

console.log(empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put if condition inside map , to for last index

```js
const empty = events.map((element, index, array){

let obj;
if(index === array.length-1){
  obj = {
      start: element.end,
   }
} else {
   obj = {
      start: element.end,
      end: array[index + 1].start
   }
}
   return obj
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The length of returned array is one element less than the length of original array. You can do it using `for` loop.

```js
const empty = [];
for(let i = 0; i < events.length - 1; i++){
   const obj = {
      start: events[i].end,
      end: events[i + 1].start
   }
   empty.push(obj) 
}
```